# Assigning state to props from redux does not work

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DisplayTable from './Table.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     menuItems: this.props.menu_items,
     searchString: '',
     displayItems: this.props.menu_items
   }
 this.search = this.search.bind(this);
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
   this.props.get_menu_items_api(false);
 }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   this.setState({ menuItems: nextProps.menu_items })
}

handleChange(e, isEnter) {
 const searchData = () => {
  let tempMenuProductDetails = this.props.menu_items;
  const filterArray = tempMenuProductDetails.reduce((result, category) => {
    if (category.categoryName.toLowerCase()
   .indexOf(this.state.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      result.push(category);
    }
    if (category.productList && category.productList.length > 0) {
      category.productList = category.productList.reduce((productListResult, 
      productList) => {
        if (!!productList.productName && 
            productList.productName.toLowerCase()
           .indexOf(this.state.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        {
          productListResult.push(productList);
        }
        return productListResult;
      }, []);
    }

    return result;
    }, []);
     this.setState({
     displayItems: filterArray
   }, function () {
    console.log(this.state.displayItems);
   })
   console.log(filterArray);
   }
   if (!isEnter) {
    this.setState({
     searchString: e.target.value
  });
  } else {
  searchData();
 }
  }

 search(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  this.handleChange(e, true);
 }
  this.handleChange(e, false);
 }

 render() {
   console.log(this.state.displayItems);
   console.log(this.props.menu_items);
   console.log(this.state.menuItems);
   return (
      <DisplayTable dataProp={this.state.displayItems} editFuncProp=
       {this.props.edit_menu_items_api} />  )
         }
   }

  export default App;
```

---

I have this search function in this file that does not update the value of props coming from the container of redux. Now when I pass {this.state.displayItems} in menu ,it does not display the data.

---

But when I pass {this.props.menu_items} it displays the data and I am not able to modify this.props.menu_items on the basis of search.
I have tried this code . what should i do?

[image: This is the console.]

Comment: It does not look like you establish a connection to Redux anywhere in the code you have provided. Are you using react-redux in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that, initially `this.props.menu_items` is an empty array and only after some API call the value is updated and you get the returned array on the second render, thus if you use it like

```
<DisplayTable dataProp={this.props.menu_items} editFuncProp=
   {this.props.edit_menu_items_api} />
```

it works. Now that you use

```
<DisplayTable dataProp={this.state.displayItems} editFuncProp=
   {this.props.edit_menu_items_api} />
```

and displayItems is only initialized in the constructor which is only executed once at the time, component is mounted and hence nothing is getting displayed.

The solution seems to be that you update the `displayItems` state in `componentWillReceiveProps`  and call the search function again with the current search string so that you search results are getting updated.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DisplayTable from './Table.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     menuItems: this.props.menu_items,
     searchString: '',
     displayItems: this.props.menu_items
   }
 this.search = this.search.bind(this);
 this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
   this.props.get_menu_items_api(false);
 }

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   this.setState({ menuItems: nextProps.menu_items, displayItems: nextProps.menu_items })
   this.handleChange(null, true);
}

handleChange(e, isEnter) {
 const searchData = () => {
  let tempMenuProductDetails = this.props.menu_items;
  const filterArray = tempMenuProductDetails.reduce((result, category) => {
    if (category.categoryName.toLowerCase()
   .indexOf(this.state.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      result.push(category);
    }
    if (category.productList && category.productList.length > 0) {
      category.productList = category.productList.reduce((productListResult, 
      productList) => {
        if (!!productList.productName && 
            productList.productName.toLowerCase()
           .indexOf(this.state.searchString.toLowerCase()) > -1)
        {
          productListResult.push(productList);
        }
        return productListResult;
      }, []);
    }

    return result;
    }, []);
     this.setState({
     displayItems: filterArray
   }, function () {
    console.log(this.state.displayItems);
   })
   console.log(filterArray);
   }
   if (!isEnter) {
    this.setState({
     searchString: e.target.value
  });
  } else {
  searchData();
 }
  }

 search(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  this.handleChange(e, true);
 }
  this.handleChange(e, false);
 }

 render() {
   console.log(this.state.displayItems);
   console.log(this.props.menu_items);
   console.log(this.state.menuItems);
   return (
      <DisplayTable dataProp={this.state.displayItems} editFuncProp=
       {this.props.edit_menu_items_api} />  )
         }
   }

  export default App;
```